# (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the PutRecord operation: Stream request-data-debugger under account xxxxxxx

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Here is my code

```
aws kinesis put-record --stream-name request-data-debugger --data file://payload.json --partition-key 1
```

When I tried to put data to kinesis. It always says,

> "(ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the PutRecord operation:
>   Stream request-data-debugger under account xxxxxxx "

But I have created the kinesis, stream with the name of `request-data-debugger`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem will occur when you create the stream in a different region and you try to access it using different region. 
Check which region your stream was created in and update it example below,

```
aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [****************HATQ]:
AWS Secret Access Key [****************88/U]:
Default region name [us-east-2]: <acutual region>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the region to the same region where the stream is created.