# ResourceNotFoundException: Stream not found under account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891038/resourcenotfoundexception-when-calling-the-putrecord-operation-stream-request) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55040983/resourcenotfoundexception-while-adding-data-to-kinesis-firehose-stream-using-lam) but could not be solved by their answers.

I am trying to create a simple stream in AWS using kinesis firehose to stream data to s3 buckets. Both stream and bucket are located at `us-east-1` as specified at [this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=159318&tstart=0).

Then I created an user with all possible inline policies available to kinesis (specially PutRecord). I double checked that the region is the same for the bucket and the stream, and double checked the stream name.

After `aws configure` on my computer I have tried to run:

```
aws kinesis put-record --stream-name my-stream-name --data file://payload.json --partition-key 1
```

But I receive `ResourceNotFoundException ... Stream my-stream-name under account ... not found`.

I've been trying to figure out what can be the issue for days and honestly I am out of ideas after searching everywhere and rebuilding the stream so many times for multiple regions, users and policies.

Anyone has had this issue before and manage solve it? Any ideas of what can be missing? Any suggestions of tutorials doing a simple stream from python -> kinesis -> s3 that I can try?

Thank you all !

Comment: Have you tried adding `--region us-east-1` to the command to explicitly make sure it's using the correct region? You can also add the `--debug` flag to verify it's using the correct endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have just tried, `--region us-east-1` didn't work. I am analyzing the debug output.

Comment: I am not the root user, can it be related to some IAM permission that I am not aware of?

Comment: Its not about root. Maybe you are using wrong account for AWS CLI.

Comment: I just generated a new access key for the user and used `aws configure` on a new terminal (to ensure no environment variables are interfering). Double checked the region, still not working =(

Maybe is some IAM permission missing to the created user? But I don't know what else can be, I gave all kinesis inline policies and access to all resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using "kinesis data stream" APIs to ingest record to "kinesis firehose". Thats why you are getting resource not found exception, because it is looking under kinesis data stream resources

Try this one -

```
aws firehose put-record --delivery-stream-name <value> --record <value>
```

[firehose put-record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/firehose/put-record.html)

Comment: Thank you! you are absolutely right! It escaped me because of the ambiguous naming.

Comment: If using AWS SDK JS V3, its the Firehose Client you want!